# What does `#{*.inspect}` mean?

Tags: ruby

I have a question regarding `puts #{parse_options.inspect}`. `parse_options` is a function defined as:

```
def parse_options
  options = {}
  case ARGV[1]
  when "-e"
    options[:e] = ARGV[2]
  when "-d"
    options[:d] = ARGV[2]
  end
  options
end
```

Its output is the value of the `options` hashmap. What I want to know is how `inspect` is supposed to work.

Answer (score 5):

`"#{ expression }"` is an [expression substitution](http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/syntax.html#exprsub): place in the string the result of evaluating the expression. `parse_options` is a method call, it returns the `options` [hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#hash) (return is implicit in Ruby). `{}` constructs an empty hash. [`inspect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-inspect) is a method on `hash`, it dumps the hash.

So it reads as follow: place in the string the evaluation of calling `inspect` on the hash returned by `parse_options` (well, it should be the result of *sending* `inspect` to the hash, details...).

Answer (score 1):

Inspect returns the hash as string
see the documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-inspect